# Fetching request returning nil after migration with renaming ID

Tags: xcode, core-data, xcdatamodel

I have a problem with my migration, for exemple:

Version1:

- Column aa (renaming ID: none)
- Column bb (renaming ID: none)
- Column cc (renaming ID: none)

Version2:

- Column ab (renaming ID: aa)
- Column bb (renaming ID: none)
- Column cc (renaming ID: none)

Version3:

- Column ac (renaming ID: ab)
- Column bc (renaming ID: bb)
- Column cc (renaming ID: none)

Wehn I do a fetch request on my version 3, I get nil for my column ac, but the two others works as well, I tried something: delete the renaming ID in version 2 for my first column and here its working !!

So we can't use renaming ID two times again ?